# Docker mysql error | [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a Next js application that I'm trying to dockerize. It shows an error while migrating Prisma. It uses MySQL as a base

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: discord-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    networks:
      - shared-network

  frontend:
    container_name: discord-frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - shared-network

networks:
  shared-network:
```

Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:18 as development

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx prisma migrate deploy && pnpm run dev"]
```

when i run docker-compose up it shows the following error

```
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31 21:31:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31 21:31:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31 21:31:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31T21:31:03.393906Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) initializing of server in progress as process 42
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31T21:31:03.395199Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31T21:31:03.395206Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31T21:31:03.395269Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
discord-mysql     | 2023-12-31T21:31:03.395427Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that You pointed `/var/lib/mysql/data`,

but data dir is: `/var/lib/mysql`, that's why /var/lib/mysql which is being created is different.

fix mount point: `- ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql/data`

make sure `./mysql_data` is empty, then start docker.

next time it will not be different.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: discord-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - shared-network

  frontend:
    container_name: discord-frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - shared-network

networks:
  shared-network:
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i delete this mysql_data now It shows as  Permission denied
as I'm not the owner

Comment: @NayanPrasadPK  seems like docker created files with root or docker user ownership. So You have to run as privileged user: `sudo rm -rf path/to/mysql_data`

Answer (score 0):

the problem with volume path:

```
volumes:
    - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

It says that `data` folder is not empty.
I think `data` folder is used before by another docker container that's why it is not empty.

Use this command `docker system prune --volumes`.

Also try changing `data` directory if problem still there.

```
volumes:
    - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql/storage
```

Comment: No this is not working. Still showing the same error

Comment: he mounted local directory to internal path. deleting volume is not solution